# Does Amazon API Gateway deployed in GovCloud spawn a Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

Some on my team believe this cannot be true, but I'd like a definitive answer.

I have seen, but cannot currently find, an article somewhere showing how to see in logs API Gateway spawning its CloudFront distribution.  If someone could show me how to do that, I'd have my answer.  (Just answering the question would be OK, too :-)

Thanks!

Comment: When used outside of GovCloud, API Gateway spawns an "invisible" CloudFront distribution -- it's not visible in any logs because it is not associated with your AWS account -- it's associated with an official service account owned by API Gateway instead of you. You can't see it or modify it, you aren't billed for it, and if you use API caching, that is provided by a dedicated, private cache, not the CloudFront cache. In light of all that, I'm not sure why API Gateway in GovCloud would be any different.  Your thoughts?

Comment: I don't have a GovCloud account available to test on, but if you set up an API Gateway API there and send a request to it, and it has an `X-Amz-Cf-Id` response header in each response, along with the other typical signs of CloudFront, such as `X-Cache` (which is present but has no real meaning in an API Gateway context,) and `Via: ...cloudfront.net` then there's not much room for speculation whether it's happening or not... but in light of the above, it may not be especially relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Michael for your comments showing me how to do this.

I sent requests to demo APIs in both us-west-1 and us-gov-west-1, and the response headers indicated a cloudfront distribution in front of the API in us-west-1, but not in front of the API in us-gov-west-1.  So, my teammates are correct.

No cloudfront distribution for GovCloud-based API-Gateway-generated API's.